# Pass Value from View to Controller Action

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I made a table in Rails:

```
<table class="table_box">
      <%= table_head([
          {text: "wanted",       width: "30%"},
          {text: "Skill",              width: "30%"},
          {text: "Duration (In months)", width: "30%"},
          {text: "Proficiency",      width: "10%"}])%>

   <tbody id="skill">
   <% skills.each do |skill| %>
        <tr class="<%= cycle("tr_box","tr_box odd",:name=>"details")%>">
        <% contains_skill = user_skills.include? skill
             indeex = user_skills.index(skill) if contains_skill
         has_experience = (indeex ? user_experience[indeex] : '')
         has_proficiency = (indeex ? user_proficiency[indeex] : '')
      %>
      <%= table_row([
          {:text=>check_box_tag("checkbox[]",value = "1",checked = contains_skill)},
          {:text=>skill},
          {:text=> (number_field_tag 'quantity', has_experience, in: 1...5)},
          {:text=> (select_tag "credit_card", options_for_select([ '','Expert', 'Average','Beginner' ], has_proficiency))},
         ])%>
  </tr>
  <% end %>
        <div class="clear"></div>
      </tbody>
  </table>
```

Now I want all the parameters (values of table) to go into my controller so I can process them.  I tried making a button:

```
<%= button_to "New", action: "update" %>
```

but this didn't work.
How can I get the values from the table into the controller?

Comment: Use a form: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html

Comment: tried the form but my implementation does not work

Comment: You need to wrap input fields in a form tag whose action points to the route mapped to your controller action.  Also, use `submit_tag` instead of `button_to`. http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper.html#method-i-submit_tag

Comment: You have to create a form for passing the input (all the data in those checkboxes and selects) to the update path. Check that out here: [Form Helpers](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html) Basically the form helpers let rails know what controller to use and what type of data (usually a model with attributes) should be used. You'll also need to add update method to the controller and route to your routes file.

Answer (score 0):

If the level of complexity of the form exceeds the simplest of forms then the simple form gem could be a big help.

Check it out here: https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form

It lets you create your form based on a model or viewmodel. Besides that it is very well documented.